# Python: Writing to file-->file empty

Tags: python

In a script data is written like so:

```
result = open("c:/filename.csv", "w")
result.write("\nTC-"+str(TC_index))
```

The .csv-file is filled with data in a while(1) loop. 
I run the script in Eclipse and exit by hitting the stop button.
Unfortunately most of the time when I open the file it is completely empty.

Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific in your question. And also give the whole code of how you file handling and if you do anything else.

Comment: Could you provide more of your code?

Comment: you need to close the file handle, otherwise none of your writes are guaranteed

Comment: The problem is, I can't close the file in my script because sometimes it takes longer to collect the data and sometimes less...

What else of the code would you need? I updated the post a little.

Answer (score 3):

To ensure a content is flushed and written to file *without* having to close the file handle:

```
import os
# ...

result.write("\nTC-"+str(TC_index))
result.flush()
os.fsync(result)
```

But of course, if you break the loop manually there's no guarantee you won't break it *between* the write and the flush, thereby failing to get the last line.   I'm unfamiliar with the Eclipse stop button but perhaps it stops execution by causing a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception to be raised.  If so you could always catch that and explicitly close the file.  Better still, use a `with` statement which will cause that to happen automatically:

```
with open("c:/filename.csv", "w") as result:
    for TC_index in range(100):  # or whatever loop
        result.write("\nTC-"+str(TC_index))
        # flush & fsync here if still necessary (but might not be)
```